# A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x20 in tid 8890 (RenderThread), pid 8833

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native, android-studio

I am getting a crash on some actions(navigating to a screen, open video player etc) in my react native app.
I have logged the error in android stdio and it was as below:

```
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x20 in tid 8890 
    (RenderThread), pid 8833
```

The crash is resolved by setting below in Android Manifest

```
 android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

But my react-native-video player is now showing black screen after setting android:hardwareAccelerated to false and I think it is not the best way to resolve it.

I don't know why I am getting this crash.
I would be thankful for any help.

Comment: if the error should occur in android emulator, then test it on a real device. android emulators seem to have multiple isses with hardware acceleration.

Comment: Have you tried to clean the Gradle and generate the build?

Comment: do you have any native(cpp library) ?

Comment: I am facing the same issue:      I am using "realm": "^10.9.1", in a “React Native application” to save some “Feed Array” data in realmDB, before closing my application.

Comment: @Bhaskar Joshi have you found any solution for this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native - Null pointer dereference after navigating to/from a page containing multiple tweets embedded inside their own WebViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56553663/react-native-null-pointer-dereference-after-navigating-to-from-a-page-containi)

Answer (score 4):

> Might be a duplicate: [React Native - Null pointer dereference after navigating to/from a page containing multiple tweets embedded inside their own WebViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56553663/react-native-null-pointer-dereference-after-navigating-to-from-a-page-containi/74577101#74577101)

My app was crashing when I was navigating away from a screen which was using [`react-native-webview`](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview) inside it.

My solution:

Example:

```js
    <WebView
      style={{ opacity: 0.99 }}
    />
```

Others used `androidHardwareAccelerationDisabled={true}`, but it didn't work for me and can also cause performance issues.

Example:

```js
    <WebView
      androidHardwareAccelerationDisabled
    />
```

Link to github discussion where I found the solution: https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues/811#issuecomment-570813204

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same problem; was using "realm": "^10.9.1", in a “React Native application” to save some “Task Data” in realmDB.

Previously I was using "React-Navigation 5x" which have a dependency on
[react-native-reanimated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-reanimated/v/2.0.0-rc.2). Now I have upgraded my code to "React-Navigation 6x", and removed old [react-native-reanimated package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-reanimated?activeTab=versions) version 2.0.0-rc.2 .